# Errors with Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, bluestacks

I'm using react-native to build an app, it's mostly based on API from another application on the network, GET/POST methods.

I'm often getting weird errors from the API when running the app on the Android Studio Emulator, like response is undefined etc. I'm using await/async and can't really see anything I'm perhaps missing await or having an unhandled promise.

The main issue, is that this happens ONLY on the Android Studio Emulator. I've tried running the app and reproduce it on 2 mobile phones, 2 tablets, and on bluestacks as emulator too.
With any of these devices I did not encounter this issue even though I tried to do exactly the same steps.

I tried increasing the emulator specs, storage, ram, anything is really high, but still it happens. I'm running the same android versions on all devices, so it shouldn't be that...

I'm not sure if there actually is some bug that I'm not catching, but then why would it reproduce only on 1 emulator(tried many options from Android Studio too).

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the network connection set to bad quality or anything like that? The emulator can be tweaked to simulate different conditions (in the settings while it's running), so make sure it's not "failing to connect"